# jQuery when data reach 0 alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

**jQuery/JavaScript**

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function min() {
                var number = parseInt($('span').html());
                return number - 30;
            }

            function add() {
                var number = parseInt($('span').html());
                return number + 31;
            }
            $("#container").click(function () {
                $('span').text(min());
            });
            $("#box").click(function () {
                $('span').text(add());
            });

            var time = parseInt($('b').html());
            if (time <= 0) {
                alert("AAAAA");
            };



        });
```

**CSS**

```
    #container{
        background: #00ff00;
        width: 500px;
        height:500px;
    }
    #box{

        background: black;
        width: 100px;
        height:100px;   
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="container">
        <span> 60 </span> 
        <div id="box"> </div>
    </div>
```

when you click on  you text in  change for +31 and -30 so you will got 61 because default is 60 and but if you click on  text in span will change for -30 only and it will display 30 i wish to alert when text in span reach 0 i made this but didn't work.
does any one know how to fix it?

Comment: I want to point out there are a multitude of ways to do this... check out this example as well... http://jsfiddle.net/9bov7z8k/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I'm not understanding completely to you. Maybe this the next link can help you.

You have some errors, check the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/b4kjhrcb/).

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $span = $('span');
    function min() {
        var number  =   parseInt($span.html());
        return number - 30;
    }
    function add() {
        var number  =   parseInt($span.html());
        return number + 31;
    }
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $('span').text(min());
        checkTime();
    });
    $("#box").click(function(){
        $('span').text(add());
        checkTime();
    });

    function checkTime() {
        debugger
        var time =  parseInt($span.html());
        if (time <= 0) {
            alert("AAAAA");
        }; 
    }  
});
```

Please next time publish your problem in JSfiddle or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're selector to get the span is incorrect. You also need to execute the check after you decrement the value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function min() {
        var number  =   parseInt($('span').html());
        return number - 30;
    }
    function add() {
        var number  =   parseInt($('span').html());
        return number + 31;
    }
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $('span').text(min());
        CheckValue();
    });
    $("#box").click(function(){
        $('span').text(add());
    });

    function CheckValue() {
        var val =  parseInt($('#container > span').html());
        if (val <= 0) {
            alert("AAAAA");
        }
    }
);
```